# R: Creating a Dataframe composed of existing columns in separate files

Tags: r

I've had to export 70+ of the same report for different subsets of data. They all have the same filename like "Campus X Item Analysis.csv" where X is the name of each campus.

I need to create a single dataframe where the columns are the 8th column from each of the files, and the columns are titled with the name of the subset. This will have to come from the file name, as for some reason the report does not include the name of the subset anywhere.

This is my first time asking a question so thanks in advance and let me know if you need to know anything else.

I'll try to be concrete about what I have/need.
I have a list of files:

```
Campus 1 Item Analysis.csv
Campus 2 Item Analysis.csv
Campus 3 Item... and so on
```

Each file has identically formatted data.

```
Campus 1 Item Analysis.csv:
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8    9...
[A1]  [B1]  [C1]  [D1]  [E1]  [F1]  [G1]  [H1]  [I1]
[A2]  [B2]  [C2]  [D2]  [E2]  [F2]  [G2]  [H2]  [I2]
```

I'm looking to aggregate the 8th column from every file into a single dataframe, preferably with them labeled by the campus.

```
Campus 1     Campus 2     Campus 3...
[H1]         [H1]         [H1]
[H2]         [H2]         [H2]
[H3... and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I spent all day hitting my head against the wall and figured it out.

```
fullnames<-list.files()

alldata<-lapply(fullnames,read.csv)
col8<-lapply(alldata,'[[',8)
final<-do.call(cbind,col8)

shortnames<-gsub(" Item Analysis.csv","",fullnames)
colnames(final)<-shortnames

write.csv(final,"Combined Data.csv")
```

I assume this is really sloppy, but I ended up getting what I needed.
The "shortnames" list was just me trimming the suffix from the filename to make things more tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Without very much information to work on, I would recommend `list.files()` and looping through them.

```
files <- list.files()

for(i in 1:length(files)){
f<-read.csv(files[i])
assign(files[i], f)}

tmp <- mget(ls())

dat <- c()
dat_name <- c()
for(i in 1:length(tmp)){
dat <- c(dat, tmp[[i]][,8])
dat_name <- c(dat_name, rep(names(tmp)[i], nrow(tmp[[i]])))
}
```

You can speed things up if you use `lapply` instead of my loops, but not sure if my solution is exactly what you are after. It should read in all your files in `getwd()`, if there are files in that directory that you don't want, use the`pattern` argument of `list.files`, similar for `mget` which groups all objects into a list. If there are other object in your R environment use the `pattern` argument in `ls()`.

The read in files loop should rename the dataframes to file names, I'm assuming those names will be passed to the names of the tmp list. I've then made two vectors (which you can compile to a df), one with the data from column 8 of all the files and one with the names of the lists they came from, they should be equal length. If you want the eighth columns of each files in a separate column of one df that is easy to, use `rbind` in the second loop.

This is obviously untested and may contain errors, so run it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to troubleshoot with me! I tried running your script and came up with the following: 

"Error in tmp[[i]][, 8] : incorrect number of dimensions"

I printed your lists and everything looked correct, so I'm not sure what the issue would be. In the mean-time, I've beefed up by original post, and I'm going to spot-check my data to make sure everything is set up correctly.

Comment: Not sure why the error, and without the data I was unable to test anything. Nevertheless you got there in the end. Glad you used `lapply`, I find for loop easier to explain, but lapply is much more efficient in this case

Comment: No sweat, now I know what to post next time around. Thanks again!